# How to add a Facebook share button that shares specific image from web page?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, php, share-button

I am trying to add a Facebook share button to an interactive page I am working on. On this web page users can manipulate a customizable image by selecting different colors to appear on the image. I'd like to know if there is any way I can add a Facebook share button that shares their finalized image.

The web page is a PHTML file and I have successfully added a plain Facebook share button to the page that just shares a link to the web page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only way to set the thumbnail image to be used at runtime is by using the Feed dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Update the Open Graph meta tag with the link of your final image and when the user Share the page on Facebook, the final image will be displayed as a thumbnail.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yoursite.com/images/final.jpg" />
```